# Report error "eaddrinuse" but there is no port occupied in "netstat" or "lsof -i:port"

Tags: erlang

{error_logger,{{2013,10,14},{12,31,31}},"Protocol: ~p: register/listen error: ~p~n",["inet_tcp",eaddrinuse]}

Can anyone give some advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely (assuming that the port isn't being used by another program) your application is trying to listen on the same port twice. So the first time it opened the port for listening it would succeed, and the second time it would fail with an error.

I have had this happen to me before, so try logging what your application is doing on both successes and failures to understand the real issue a little better.

Also its a little hard to tell where the error could be coming from because no sample code, or context is provided.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I also think it is hard to tell where is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For people who tries to run 2 rabbitmq on same server, don't uncomment two tcp port with same port in /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf. It should be like:

```
listeners.tcp.default = 5700


## To listen on a specific interface, provide an IP address with port.
## For example, to listen only on localhost for both IPv4 and IPv6:
##
# IPv4
#listeners.tcp.local    = 127.0.0.1:5700
# IPv6
# listeners.tcp.local_v6 = ::1:5700
```

For ipv4 and ipv6 change the port, otherwise you'll face with eaddrinuse error.